# How can I use timeit() efficiently without allocating parameters per function each time?

Tags: matlab, performance, timeit

My code is quite a long one and I want to dissect each section and loop to figure out the computational time, easy task using `tic` `toc` but can I adjust `timeit()` in a similar way, and the examples in matlab documentation regarding `timeit()` are too simple to fit in an average solution.

Comment: Have you considered using the [profiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)?

Comment: I have but i need to check many code section in a given code,meaning i won't be checking the entire function rather  many segments of it.

Comment: `timeit` calls the code under evaluation multiple times to reduce uncertainty due to jitter, etc., so it needs to be in its own function.

Your code needs to be refactored for that, or you need to divided it into separate components. It would make sense to have each of these components as individual function. Otherwise, just use `tic` and `toc`.

Comment: I just ran a classification part and gave 3.613610 seconds the first time,then around 0.739692 seconds the times after using tic toc,why's there such a difference